# Why are all my PCIe M.2 SSD's running slow?

Tags: ssd, performance, pci-express, m.2

I recently bought a Lenovo Y7000 which came with a main 256 GB PCIe solid state drive, and an external 1 TB SATA hard drive. I bought a Samsung 970 Evo Plus 1 TB PCIe M.2 SSD on amazon, and installed it instead of the 256 GB drive it had.

When I ran user benchmarks on my machine, every component was better than average, except the samsung solid state drive that was still very fast (~1600 MB/s), but much worse than expected (bottom 13% according to the user benchmark website). I thought I just got unlucky, so I returned it and ordered another one, and the new one would oscillate from bottom 10% to bottom 20% in the benchmarks.

I wanted to get another one, but then I saw that they just went out of stock, so I think I might have just gotten a bad batch of them, so I ordered the XPG SX8200 Pro 1 TB drive, which is supposed to run at similar speeds, and if I got the average speed on that drive, it would be well higher than the speeds I got with my well below average samsung ones. However this one also performs on the bottom 15%, running at < 1100 MB/s.

At this point I thought that something was wrong with my motherboard, so I benchmarked the original 256 GB drive that came with that machine, and that ranked on the 68th percentile, which was much more like what I was hoping for (albeit it only ran at around 900 MB/s).

Do you think I'm just getting really unlucky with my purchases, and I should keep trying, is my computer in some way not compatible with these drives, or is there something else you recommend?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Is there any indication the drive isn't actually working correctly? Comparing against other people's benchmarks is NOT how you determine whether a piece of equipment is working OK. The equipment is working OK if it meets the standard defined for it, not the standard defined for everyone else. You've told us, essentially, that you are unhappy with the comparison, but you have not indicated there is actually any problem here.

Comment: So please use the EDIT button and give us more concrete information about the actual problem.

Comment: @music2myear I'm not sure what you're saying. The SSD is working OK in that it runs, but if it's working for me much slower than it works for everyone else, it is reasonable to believe that it's due to something. My question was whether you think it's due to a) my computer configuration is less compatible somehow with those drives than others' configurations, b) I'm just getting unlucky. I was asking for your feedback as to what you think the discrepancy between my setup and others being benchmarked is. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: SuperUser is a site designed to find specific answers to specific question. Looking for feedback is soliciting opinions, which is not what we're designed to do. You've indicated that your scores are low compared to others, but that they fall within the range of correctly functioning hardware. This means you have an annoyance, but not an actual problem. If you can narrow your issue down to an actual problem, we may be able to find an actual solution for you. But annoyances and opinions just aren't what we're really suited to handle here.

Comment: @music2myear Oh, thanks for that advice, sorry about that. Do you happen to know of any website which is better suited for my query?

Comment: Have you trued benchmarking from a USB booted Linux? Could the issues be due to other siftware running in the background?

Comment: @davidgo Not yet, I'll try that, thanks! I did try only running it when the task manager showed very low disk and cpu usage, but I know that's not perfect.